# When should roscors's ros_master_uri not just be localhost?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the computer running **roscore**, I understand that this is almost always sufficient.

`export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311`

Under what special circumstances does that computer need a specific IP address of ROS_MASTER? And does it ever need ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME? My reasoning is that MASTER_URI points to roscore, which is itself, so localhost should always be good enough. I can't think of other scenarios, but they probably do exist!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298179/when-should-roscors%27s-ros_master_uri-not-just-be-localhost?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-23**:
Are you asking if there are conditions when you should use an IP address in `ROS_MASTER_URI` instead of a hostname? (E.g., `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.0:11311` instead of `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://myrobot:11311`.)

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-23**:
Note specifically I am talking about the computer running Roscore. My reasoning is that MASTER_URI points to roscore, which is itself, so localhost should always be good enough. I can't think of other scenarios, but they probably do exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using localhost is not *always* good enough for your `ROS_MASTER_URI`. It may be for many situations (especially when only using one computer), but not always. `ROS_MASTER_URI` needs to be accessible to every computer that you're going to be using and that's just not possible if you set `ROS_MASTER_URI` to localhost because every machine will be looking for `roscore` at its own localhost instead of the one that you intend.

Therefore, if you're going to be doing anything over a network, the address needs to be accessible over that network.

Check out the tutorial for [running ROS on multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
I believe @pitosalas is wondering whether there are any situations in which you would configure `ROS_MASTER_URI` with a different value than `localhost` for *the master itself* (ie: the machine running `roscore`).